# ¿Cómo puedo usar un bootstrap modal login en Spring MVC?

Tags: bootstrap, java-ee, spring-mvc

Soy nuevo en esta comunidad, y la verdad es que esta genial.
Bueno aquí mi pregunta: ¿Cómo puedo mapear bootstrap modal login desde un controlador de Spring MVC? y ¿cómo puedo hacer el login por código sin tener que registrar nada en el web.xml?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/modal_login.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/npm.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <c:url value="/mwp/inicio" var="urlInicio"/>
    <c:url value="/mwp/sobremi" var="urlSobreMi"/>
    <c:url value="/mwp/cursos" var="urlCursos"/>
    <c:url value="/mwp/contactar" var="urlContactar"/>
    <c:url value="/mwp/login" var="urlLogin"/>
    <c:url value="/mwp/logout" var="urlLogout"/>
    <!-- Menu -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="${urlInicio}">Inicio <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="${urlSobreMi}">Sobre mi <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="${urlCursos}">Mis cursos <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span></a></li>
                        <c:if test="'<%= request.getUserPrincipal() != null%>'">
                            <li><a href="${urlContactar}">Contactar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
                        </c:if>                        
                </ul>    
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test='<%= request.getUserPrincipal() == null%>'>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Iniciar sesión <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                <a href="#">Salir <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--Modal Login -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="loginmodal-container">
                <h1>Iniciar sesión</h1><br>
                <form action="${urlLogin}" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Iniciar sesión">
                </form>
                <div class="login-help">
                    <a href="#">Crear cuenta</a> - <a href="#">Recuperar contraseña</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Este es un jsp que incluyo en todos los otros a modo cabecera ya que contiene el menú y el modal login.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Comentarte que hacerlo solo con spring MVC es viable pero mas tedioso que usar algo que te da el framework de spring security.

Mediante Spring MVC, se podria hacer con una llamada a tu controller que se podria denominar "/login" al darle al vinculo llamaria a tu controller (login) y este le enviaria a la jsp que muestras. El codigo podria ser algo asi:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private AdministrationManager administrationManager;

@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public ModelAndView loadHome() {        
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    mv.setViewName("login");//esto llamaria a tu jsp login.jsp      

    return mv;
}

//he usado username y password como variables de tu formulario, la acction tendria que llamar a este metodo del controller.
@RequestMapping(value = "/processlogin/{username}/{password}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ProcessLogin(@PathVariable String username,@PathVariable String password, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder){
    boolean isValidUser=false;
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    //Codigo para chequear el usuario y el password...
    isValidUser = ChequearUsuarioLogado(username,password);

    if (isValidUser)
      mv.setViewName("home");//llamamos al home con el usuario guardado en una cookie o se lo pasamos por parametro...
    else
      mv.setViewName("login");
    return mv;
}

}
```

Por otro lado, recomendarte que uses mejor Spring Security para gestión de la seguridad de tu web pues todo el código anterior de los controller te lo ahorrarías y te puedo asegurar que te facilita bastante la tarea.
Te recomiendo leas la documentacion de la ultima version de Spring Security en el siguiente vinculo: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Espero que sea de tu ayuda..